# Find all $g(x)$ such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

For a given function $f(x)$ I want to find all functions $g(x)$ such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$.

Two solutions are always $g(x)=x$ and $g(x)=f(x)$, but are there any more?

Initially I wondered this for $f(x)=e^x$, but then also wondered about the general case.

Comment: Related: [In which cases are $(f \circ g)(x) = (g \circ f)(x)$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645367) and [If $f \circ g = g \circ f$ does that mean that both functions are to and from the same set and both are bijections? Does it tell us anything else?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109546)

Comment: This depends on the function obviously. For example, if $f$ is invertible, you can set $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$. In particular, for $f(x)=e^x$, can take $g(x)=\ln(x)$.

Comment: A [classic result of Ritt](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/11442/242) gives a complete answer for polynomials and rational functions.